# localStorage.getItem não funciona

Tags: localstorage

Boa noite, poderiam me ajudar?
Estou tentando passar os dados de uma pagina pra outra mas o campo fica vazio.
pagina 1: onde pego o dado.
pagina 2: onde quero inserir aquele dado.

PAGINA 1:

`<h1 class="tituloProd">Arroz Tio João integral tipo 1 - 5KG</h1>`

PAGINA 2:

```
<p class="descricaoProduto">Descricao aqui<p> 

      $('#btnCompra').click (function(){
       localStorage.setItem('tituloProd', 'arroz');
       $('.descricaoProduto').text(localStorage.getItem('tituloProd'));
  });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT COMPLETO:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnCompra').click (function(){
  $('#modalProduto').modal('hide'); 
  $('#divInfo').css('display','block'); /* exibe uma div de alerta */
  var titulo = $('#tituloProd').text();
  localStorage.setItem("titulo_produto", titulo);
});

$('#carrinho').click (function(){
  $('#descricaoProduto').text(localStorage.getItem("titulo_produto"));
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Então Weslley, pelo código que postou, vc está setando e pegando o valor na mesma página e não setando o valor na página 1 e pegando na página 2, o certo seria:

## Pagina 1

```
HTML - Página 1

<h1 id="tituloProd">Arroz Tio João integral tipo 1 - 5KG</h1>
```

---

```
JS - Página 1

//pega o texto
let titulo = $("#tituloProd").text();

// titulo_produto é a chave e titulo o valor que serão armazenados no localStorage   
localStorage.setItem("titulo_produto", titulo);
```

## Página 2

```
HTML - Página 2

<p id="descricaoProduto"></p>
```

---

```
JS - Página 2

$("#btnCompra").click(function(){
  // Aqui obtém o valor através da chave
  $("#descricaoProduto").text(localStorage.getItem("titulo_produto"));
});
```

**Também sugiro trocar classes por id para setar e pegar valores específicos na página.**

Comment: Boa tarde LeAndrade! Obrigado pela resolução, ele funcionou! Agora estou com um outro problema. O meu objetivo era: quando clicasse no carrinho, o campo fosse setado na div do produto, isso deu certo, mas o valor aparece por um curto periodo de tempo e depois some, ou seja, quando eu clico no carrinho, aparece o campo setado e depois desaparece, voce sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Posta toda a função pra ver, com o código que postou não tem como saber.

Comment: Pronto! Inseri a função completa

Comment: Cara tá bem confuso o seu código, mas, pelo que postou não da para ver o pq está ocorrendo esse comportamento de mostrar e depois sumir, pode ter relação com o ** $('#modalProduto').modal('hide');**, que isto é para esconder o modal com id **modalProduto**.

Comment: boa noite LeAndreade, descobri o problema. O meu "btnCarrinho" era um link (<a>) e toda vez que clicava nele, a pagina atualizava. O motivo do valor sumir não entendi, ja que localStorage permanece apos atualizacoes, mas removi a tag a e deu tudo certo.